# AWS Elastic Beanstalk and Django template dir

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-templates, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Where are template directories supposed to be placed in the project tree and what is to be set for TEMPLATE_DIRS so that AWS beanstalk can read it?

If I have /template in the project root, I supposed it's `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'template')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'template')`

Answer (score 0):

step 1:
 you provide the correct line of codes pointing to the 'template' folder.
 Just place it in project-name/settings.py under TEMPLATE_DIRS.

step 2:
Create 'template' folder at the project's root.
for example (project: mysite): mysite/template/

Comment: *you provide the correct line of codes pointing to the 'template' folder* this was more or less my question: how to point to the 'template' folder. but yeah, turns out `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'template')` works. thanks